# Is it possible to have react access device storage

Tags: reactjs, xamarin

I have a xamarin app that saves push notification data to the device storage. I'm wondering if it is at all possible to access this storage from a react app at all. Or is there a way I can create a cookie or some other way to save this data to the browser storage?

I am not using a native react app.

Comment: in iOS, no, sandboxing prevents apps from reading each others data.  In Android I believe you can write data to a shared location on external storage.

Comment: Also in Android there is a mixture of different behaviors  in different versions and you can't do this on certain versions which makes your task not market friendly.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look at a different solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this on ios. Although you can call a react function with webview.evaluatejavascript and send data to the app with post message